# Efficient way of inserting and viewing unique id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which multiple users can access. Each time the form is opened, a sequential, unique id is created and placed on the form right when the user opens it. The id being unique is very important.

To achieve this, when the user opens the form, a post request is sent to the server and inserts the max id +1 into the database. On success, I send a get request to get the max value from the database. This id needs to show on the form.

This method works ok...*sometimes*. I usually see the id being incremented on the form each time I open it. But there are times when I see the same id twice in a row when the form is opened:

```
//This ajax requests posts the max value +1 to the DB and on success, gets the max value 
//which should be the next id in the sequence

$.ajax({
      url: "/sendsDataToServer",  
      success: function(data) {
         sendGetRequestToGetMaxValue(); 
      }
   });

//insert max id  + 1 to database
INSERT INTO TABLE (id) VALUES (COALESCE(MAX(id), 0) +1 );

//Get max id from database
SELECT MAX(id) FROM TABLE;
```

Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do? If so, how can I make this process better? I fear that since I'm seeing the same id generated twice in a row, that there may be other issues with my approach, for example, if multiple users access the form at the same time, they may get the same id, and that would be an issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this approach is fundamentally wrong. what database is it about?

Comment: I'm using postgres. But I can see the correct value in the database. It's the get request that gets the wrong value sometimes.

Comment: `Java` and `JavaScript` are not the same thing, please use correct tags.

Comment: I know they're not the same, I'm using Java for the backend so that's why it was included.

Comment: It is precisely with this approach that there is no guarantee that you will receive the correct value. postgresql offers RETURNING from insert statement. use it to return the generated id.

Comment: Why you need to show the Id before inserting in table, just set id column unquie or autoincrement in sql , after insert show the Id in alert or div if you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to create a table with a serial primary key field. This will ensure a unique ID for each record.

```
test=# create table tbl (id serial primary key, name varchar(255));
CREATE TABLE
test=# \d tbl
                                Table "public.tbl"
Column |          Type          |                    Modifiers                     
--------+------------------------+--------------------------------------------------
id     | integer                | not null default nextval('tbl_id_seq'::regclass)
name   | character varying(255) | 
Indexes:
    "tbl_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Adding data and displaying the generated ID can be done in two ways:
Using RETURNING in INSERT statement

```
test=# insert into tbl (name) values ('name 1') returning id;
id 
----
1
(1 row)

INSERT 0 1
test=# insert into tbl (name) values ('name 2') returning id;
id 
----
2
(1 row)

INSERT 0 1
test=# insert into tbl (name) values ('name 3') returning id;
id 
----
3
(1 row)

INSERT 0 1
```

Or use JDBC

```
public long insertName(String name) throws SQLException {
    String query = "insert into tbl (name) values (?)";

    try(PreparedStatement st = dataSource.getConnection().prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
        st.setString(1, name);
        st.executeUpdate();

        try(ResultSet rs = st.getGeneratedKeys()) {
            if(rs.next()) {
                return rs.getLong(1);
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

when you create SQL table, you can set the ID as "auto increment".
it means that every time you make a "INSERT" statement, you don't have to specify the ID, it will be generated automaticly.

In the front and, you need send only the relevent data, without id.
the back end will make the call to the DB. Its the DB responsibily to auto create the ID.

Comment: Thanks for your response...but if multiple users can access the form simultaneously, wouldn't I need to insert the max id +1, to ensure that the same id isn't generated over and over again? Each user needs a unique form id.

Comment: simultaneously is not an issue. the DB was designed to handle this.
you can see how to use it here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_using_autoincrement.htm

Comment: postgresql provides serial (bigserial) type for auto increment keys.